# How to setup multi websites in the same domain?

Tags: magento-1.9, multi-website

We have website with multi stores with different languages and currencies.

We had Problem with our payment gateway because we have only one base currency , and we want our customers to buy with different currency in each store .

I have been notified that i need to create a website for each store if i want multi base currency for each store.

Would someone please guide me step by step how to do this.

Thank you in advanced .

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to setup multiwebsite.
you can setup multistore for this

and follow instruction give in this link to setup multi currency

http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-currency-selector-to-magentos-header/

Comment: No , it does not work for my case ,because i need different base currency for each store.

Comment: You try this extension https://bsscommerce.com/magento-multistore-pricing.html. It give you ability to set base currency for each store in same website